# render json with two objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, render

I need to render json with two objects
How to do it well?

The initial version was:

*/controller/comments_controller.rb*

```
    def create
          ....
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @comment.commentable, flash[:notice] => t('comment.actions.added') }
            format.json { render :json => @comment }
          end
    end
```

*javascripts/comment.js:*

```
submitComment = function(form) {
  $.ajax("/comments/?format=json", {
    type: "post",
    data: form.serializeArray(),
    success: function(comment) {
      $.get("/comments/" + comment.id, function(commentHtml) {
        newComment = $(commentHtml).hide();
        commentsList = $('#' + comment.commentable_type + comment.commentable_id + 'Comments');
        commentsList.append(newComment);
        newComment.show('slow');
      });
      $(form.selector + " textarea").val("");
    },
    error: function() {
      showMessage({
        title: "Error",
        message: "Error occured. Please try resubmit the data."
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I want to add a dynamic update number of comments,, and I think to do this as:

```
def create
      ....
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @comment.commentable, flash[:notice] => t('comment.actions.added') }
        format.json { render :json => {comment: @comment, comments_count: @comment.commentable.comments.count }
      end
end
```

But I do not understand how to add comments_count to the script javascripts/comment.js.
All my attempts to insert comments_count, like:

```
$('#comments_count').html(comments_count);
```

I get an error or the answer "true"

please help me! and thanks in advance!

**====  update =====**

[eicto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815386/eicto), thank you,  current function is:

```
submitComment = function(form) {
  $.ajax("/comments/?format=json", {
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form.serializeArray(),
    success: function(comment) {
      $("h2#comments_count").text(comment.comments_count);
      $.get("/comments/" + comment.comment.id, function(commentHtml) {
        newComment = $(commentHtml).hide();
        commentsList = $('#' + comment.comment.commentable_type + comment.comment.commentable_id + 'Comments');
        commentsList.append(newComment);
        newComment.show('slow');
      });
      $(form.selector + " textarea").val("");

    },
    error: function() {
      showMessage({
        title: "Error",
        message: "Error occured. Please try resubmit the data."
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you return  object like:

`{comment: [], comments_count: 100 };` or it may be `{comment: {}, comments_count: 100 };`

anyway here only two root properties of returned object...

so you should parse it as json and place to element in callback:

```
submitComment = function(form) {
  $.ajax("/comments/?format=json", {
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json', // <- HERE
    data: form.serializeArray(),
    success: function(comment) {
      $('#comments_count').text(comment.comments_count); // <- AND HERE
      $.get("/comments/" + comment.id, function(commentHtml) {
        newComment = $(commentHtml).hide();
        commentsList = $('#' + comment.commentable_type + comment.commentable_id + 'Comments');
        commentsList.append(newComment);
        newComment.show('slow');
      });
      $(form.selector + " textarea").val("");
    },
    error: function() {
      showMessage({
        title: "Error",
        message: "Error occured. Please try resubmit the data."
      });
    }
  });
}
```

here are other strange things, like why you interpret comments array as single comment and trying to get property id of it... but it is not related to question.

Comment: comments_count updates, but then I get error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with id=undefined), and new comment did't append

Comment: see note in the end of the answer. you accessing that object incorrect andI not know structure of the object, may be you need `comment.comment.id` or `comment.comment[0].id`

Comment: add `console.log(JSON.stringify(comment));` just after `$('#comments_count').text(comment.comments_count);` check the console and show me

Comment: thanks for your help, I understand the problem,decision at the beginning of the page